# "TypeError: Rx.Observable.ofObjectChanges is not a function"

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript version.
 tried to create observer object from a class. But get the error "TypeError: Rx.Observable.ofObjectChanges is not a function"

```
`"use strict";

/// 

import Rx = require("rx");

class tester {
 public name: string;
 }

var t = new tester();
 var source = Rx.Observable.ofObjectChanges(t);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
 function (x) {
 console.log('Next: %s', x);
 },
 function (err) {
 console.log('Error: %s', err);
 },
 function () {
 console.log('Completed');
 });

t.name = "hung";
```

I tried to take some research but cannot find the solution.
 Can someone help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think rx.js project is setup poorly. I just created a new project and the following is the code needed to get `rx.all` to work:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/rx/ts/rx.all.d.ts"/>

import rx = require("rx");

// Fix rx to point to rx.all
var Rx = rx;
declare var require:any; // not needed if you have node.d.ts
Rx = require('rx/dist/rx.all');

console.log(Rx.Observable.ofObjectChanges);
```

## Discussion

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/1147#issuecomment-190530438

Comment: Thanks  for your time: that is also my question :).  your answer works for me.